# Grails <textarea>, how to no-scalable?

Tags: html, css, grails, textarea

Maybe someone can give me a hint, how to create non-scaleable textareas?

I tryed the usual stuff like :

```
<g:textArea name="tumble" value="myVtumble" rows="2" cols="2" /> 

<style>
#tumble { 
   resize: none; 
} 
//or 
#tumble {
   max-height: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
   max-width:10px:
}
</style>
```

and how do I remove the border ? `border="0"` in the attributes wont make it

Thanks a lot, hope i expressed my question understandable

Comment: It might be your browser or the way you wrote the css because this: `<g:textArea name="tumble" value="myVtumble" rows="2" cols="2" style="resize: none;"/>` worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your  doesn't have any id. So try:

```
<g:textArea name="tumble" id="tumble" value="myVtumble" rows="2" cols="2" />
```

or

```
<style>
textarea[name='tumble'] { 
   resize: none; 
} 
</style>
```

Comment: ah okay i always thought the "name" attr. equals an id thanks

Comment: no, but its a common practice to have the same id and name attribute